# How add checkbox column in OhrmList symfony 1.4?

Tags: symfony-1.4

I don't understand how can I set column with checkbox in list?!

I have class where sets column:

```
class payHeadListConfigurationFactory extends ohrmListConfigurationFactory {

    protected function init() {

        $headerArray = array();

        $header1 = new ListHeader();

        $header1->populateFromArray(array(
            'name' => 'ID',
            'isSortable' => false,
            'sortField' => null,
            'elementType' => 'label',
            'elementProperty' => array('getter' => 'getId')
        ));

        $headerArray [] = $header1;

        $header2 = new ListHeader();
        $header2->populateFromArray(array(
            'name' => 'Pay Head Name',
            'isSortable' => false,
            'sortField' => null,
            'elementType' => 'link',
            'elementProperty' => array(
                'labelGetter' => 'getName',
                'placeholderGetters' => array('id' => 'getId'),
                'urlPattern' => 'index.php/payroll/viewOnePayHead?hdnEditId={id}')

        ));
        $headerArray [] = $header2;
        $this->headers = $headerArray;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getClassName() {
        return 'payHead';
    }
}
```

And configuration for this list:

```
$configurationFactory = new payHeadListConfigurationFactory();
ohrmListComponent::setConfigurationFactory($configurationFactory);
ohrmListComponent::setListData($pensionList);
```

But when I see examples which has checkbox I don't see difference.
May be anybody know where checkbox must be set?

Comment: This is out of the context. I am using the same plugin now. May I know how to include the filters for the columns in the table(List ).

Answer (score 0):

OHRMList have config file in orangehrmCorePlugin\config\list_component.yml

In this file placed all additional config info and settings for checkboxes too.
For example,

```
Project:
  pluginName: orangehrmAdminPlugin
  hasSelectableRows: true
  unselectableRowIds: []
  idValueGetter: projectId
  title: ''
  tableWidth: 100%
  hasSummary: false
  summary: []
  buttonsPosition: before-data
  formMethod: post
  formAction: 'admin/deleteProject'
  assets: []
  jsInitMethods: []
```

And in your ProjectHeaderFactory class you need return name of this settings, like this:

```
public function getClassName() {
    return 'Project';
}
```